# Why was my revision rejected when I directly addressed the moderator comment?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

> I don't see how this answers the question. The question is, how can a
> string represent a C++ program? I don't see that this answers that
> question. It does not describe a way that a string can represent a C++
> program.

**The question is more accurately described as:

"how can a string represent a C++ program"

[so that halt decider h can examine the function f] ?**

I cited an academic paper in the field of termination analysis that suggested

> low-level intermediate languages that occur during the compilation of
> C programs to machine code have a much simpler semantics since most of
> the intricacies of C are taken care of by the compiler frontend.

Then I provided a concrete example of examining the halt status of the code sample provided in the question using a simulating halt decider to analyze the execution trace of the machine language of this code sample.

(1) In the following there is a link to the original question.
(2) The body of my revised answer that was rejected by the moderator.
(3) The original moderator comment that was addressed by my revision.

[Halting problem in C++](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111746/halting-problem-in-c)

**The question is more accurately described as:

"how can a string represent a C++ program"

[so that halt decider h can examine the function f] ?**

## screen shot of the revised answer

[image]

## end of screen shot of the revised answer

Comment: I have trouble finding the Meta question in here. Please stop pasting your main-site content everywhere.

Comment: @Raphael in order for people to review my deleted answer I must post it here.

Comment: No. If they won't review it on the main site, they certainly won't here. And it's blatantly offtopic here. You have been warned; I will close all future questions on [meta.CS] of yours that contain huge chunks of main site content, without reading them.

Comment: @Raphael If moderators insist on deleting my answer before I have a chance to address their feedback how else can I get feedback on this answer by others that can't see deleted answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my answer to make it much more clear. This time a moderator did not immediately delete the answer before I could address their issues. I rewrote the answer to fully address their issues.

[Halting problem in C++](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111746/halting-problem-in-c/157654#157654)

Answer (score 2):

> Why was my revision rejected when I directly addressed the moderator comment?

You posted two answers on the [question you link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/111746/halting-problem-in-c).

- You deleted one youself.
- The second one was deleted by a moderator with an explanatory comment, after receiving quite a few downvotes.

Note that content downvoted as much is hidden from most users anyway, for good reason.

Comment: **You simply avoided rather than answered my question. Nothing you said pertained to how I did not fully address the moderator's reason for deleting.**

Comment: If you insist, here is the verbatim comment you received: " I don't see how this answers the question. The question is, how can a string represent a C++ program? I don't see that this answers that question. It does not describe a way that a string can represent a C++ program. Also, the question is not asking for you to opine on whether the halting problem can be solved. Rather, it is asking about the standard proof of the halting problem (whether or not you believe it) and how it can be modified to apply to C++ programs. I don't see that this is answering that question, either. "

Comment: That you are insist on not reading how I did fully addressed the moderator comment and yet reject my request for review that my changes did fully address the moderator comment then you are dishonest.

Comment: If you feel you were wronged by community moderators, feel free to report the incident to SO staff.

Comment: I rewrote my answer making it much more clear and the moderator did not delete it before I had a chance to address their comment.